# Move up and down using pointer lock controls THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, camera, trigonometry

I need to move up and down using three.js's `pointerlockcontrols`. I am looking for the same kind of movement as three.js's `flycontrols`, where the amount you move up and down is proportional to the direction you are looking in (ie. if your looking north-east, you move in the Y and Z directions at the same rate).

I tried:

```
    if(keys[38] || keys[87]){
        Controls.moveForward(playerSpeed);
        Camera.position.y += Math.cos(Camera.rotation.y) * playerSpeed;
    }
```

Where keys is just a object of all the keys and whether they are down, however this didn't give the appropriate behavior, as looking straight down also moved you forward a lot.

Has anyone ever accomplished or knows how to do this?

Comment: Since you're trying to copy the behavior of `FlyControls`, have you [looked at the source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/jsm/controls/FlyControls.js) code to see how they do it?

Comment: I didn't take a look at the source code (I will once ive finished), but I saw a few places say stuff like `controls.canLookUp = true` or `controls.canMoveUp = true` for the fly controls, and that didn't work for PLC, ill look at the cource code now though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the implementation of [moveForward(distance)](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/0fbae6f682f6e13dd9eb8acde02e4f50c0b73935/examples/jsm/controls/PointerLockControls.js) to this:

```js
    moveForward(distance) {
        const camera = this.camera;

        _vector.copy(this.getDirection(_vector));

        camera.position.addScaledVector(_vector, distance);
    }
```

The original implementation uses the camera's side- and up-vectors to calculate the one pointing in the forward direction -> this enables the intended movement in the xz-plane.

My change just uses the already existing `getDirection` method and applies the travelled distance on the resulting vector.